I am having a problem with network reply stalling at 3 months behind
I have Bitcoin_wallet 'Version wallet 9.26' installed on an old Oppo R11s phone I have a message saying "Synchronizing with network, 3 months behind" When trying to transfere funds across to a Samsung S21 Ultra 5G phone I have a message saying "Currently payments are not possible because a replay is in progress". I have tryed to Reset Block Chain but as soon as it get to 3 months it stalls and will not finish. Any help would be appreciated.


I have Bitcoin_wallet 'Version wallet 9.26

The latest is 10.16, I would first backup the wallet, test recovery from the backup on a different device and then upgrade this device to 10.16 and retry synchronisation.

as it get to 3 months it stalls and will not finish. Any help would be appreciated.

I would check for active peers in the "Network Monitor" menu item. There is also a menu item for "Report issue" which might get a response from the developers if you are using the current version and not an old version.

Thank you for your reply. How would I transfer the backup to my Samsung and where will I find the backup. Also I am guessing because of the age of my phone "Oppo" I am unable to Report my problem. BTW I have the latest version on my Samsung

Thank you, you solved my issue
